# Can the complex square root of $z\sin z$ be defined in a neighborhood of the origin? (I.e., including the origin)

Tags: complex-analysis, logarithms, analyticity

Edit: on a second thought, I don't think it's possible since

$$ f(z) = \sqrt {z\sin z} = e^{\large \frac{1}{2} \log z}e^{\large \frac{1}{2} \log\sin z}$$

$$e^{\large \frac{1}{2} (\ln|z| + iArg(z))}e^{\large \frac{1}{2} (\ln|\sin(z)| +iArg(sin(z))}$$

is undefined at the origin -- we'd get a $ln|sin(0)| = ln|0|$ factor.  What do you think?  Thanks,

The problem statement is:

Consider the function $ f(z) = \sqrt {z\sin z}$ . Can $f(z)$ be defined near the origin as a single valued analytic function?

What will be the radius of convergence of the power series expansion of $f$ around $z=0$?

My thoughts:

It is tempting to say "no", since $z=0$ seems like a branch point of $f(z)$.

But a closer look at the function

$$ f(z) = \sqrt {z\sin z} = e^{\large \frac{1}{2} \log z}e^{\large \frac{1}{2} \log\sin z}$$

shows that we need to pick two branch cuts.  And if we choose both cuts to  be $\mathbb R^- \cup \{0\}$, i.e., choose the principal branch of the logarithm for *both* factors, then each factor is discontinuous and not defined on the negative real axis (plus the origin), and each jumps by a factor of $e^{\frac{1}{2} 2 \pi i} = e^{i\pi} = -1$.

However, considering both factors together, we get a total "jump" of $e^{2\pi i} =1$, and I think that now $f(z)$ has been made single-valued and analytic on the negative real axis, including the origin, and thus we get an analytic continuation onto the negative axis and the origin, so that $f(z)$ can in fact be defined near the origin as a single-valued analytic function.

What do you think?

This seems a bit too generous, though.  I feel like I have claimed that this function is *entire*, which I am almost certain cannot be true...because of the complex logarithm used to define $f(z)$.

Any ideas are welcome.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT:

$$z \sin z = z^2 \left( 1 + (\frac{\sin z}{z} -1) \right) $$

and $\phi(z) = \frac{\sin z}{z} -1$ is entire, taking value $0$ at $0$, so one can define $\sqrt{1 + \phi(z)}$ for $z$ close enough to $0$.

Comment: Hi @orangeskid, very nice factorization.  So, the complex square root of $zsin(z)$ is then well-defined near zero, and it becomes undefined, when $sin(z) = 0$, because we will  have $z^2(1 - 1)$.  The closest value in which $sin$ is $0$ is at $\pi$.  I am guessing that this must be the radius of convergence of the square root.  But...don't we still need to choose a branch cut?  Which seems like it must start from the origin...

Comment: @User001: I think that we just use the determination of the function $\sqrt{1+z}$  that is defined on the half-plane $\mathcal{Re}z> -1$. Yes, i think we could extend this root to a function say on $\mathbb{C} \backslash (-\infty, -1]$ ( a branch cut). As for the radius of convergence, it seems to be indeed $\pi$ .

Comment: @User001: Ah, I think I see your worry, the branch cut for $\sqrt{1+z}$ should make us stay from say $\pi$ in the source, not $0$. Since we compose this function with $\frac{\sin z}{z} -1$ ( we should perhaps use a different variable in $\sqrt{1+z}$ )

Comment: Hi @orangeskid, why do we move the branch cut to $[\pi, \infty)$?  What happens in between?  Say, all of the area of the disk between 0 and $\pi$?  Is the square-root just...real-valued?  Or complex-valued, single-valued?  I am a little confused about where the branch cut starts, I guess.  Thanks,

Comment: @User001: Aha, so $\frac{\sin z}{z}$ has a root at least on the disk centered at $0$ with radius $\pi$. We can extend a bit this region ( avoid the zeroes of $\frac{\sin z}{z}$)  to a simply connected region by cutting away $(-\infty, Pi]$ and $[\pi, \infty)$. I think the root can be defined on this region. Whenever a function defined on a simply connected region has no zeroes, it has a square root.  The root will not be real valued only.

Comment: Hi @orangeskid, it's just weird how, using the complex logarithm to define the square root, why we get single-valuedness inside the disk of radius $\pi$, and that we can start the branch cuts at $\pi$ instead...hmmm...maybe it is just a definition, that a branch cut starts at a branch point, which is at $z=0$ for $log(z)$, or $z=-1$ for $log(1+z)$, etc...what do you think?  Thanks,

Comment: @User001: branch cuts are so that we remove the problem points (points that map to the branch points for $z \to z^2$) and also make the domain simply connected.  This is somehow subtle: why we have a root for a function without zeroes on a simply connected domain ( no holes).

Comment: Ok got it -- thanks so much for your help, @orangeskid :-)

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Consider the problem in $0 < |z| < \pi$. You want
\begin{align}
        F(z) &= \exp\left\{\frac{1}{2}\log(z\sin z)\right\} \\
      &= C\exp\left\{\frac{1}{2}\int_{\pi/2}^{z}\frac{\frac{d}{dz}(w\sin w)}{w\sin w}dw\right\} \\
      &= C\exp\left\{\frac{1}{2}\int_{\pi/2}^{z}\frac{\cos w}{\sin w}+\frac{1}{w} dw\right\}.
\end{align}
The integral is any path from $\pi/2$ to $z$ that remains in $0 < |z| < \pi$.
Define
$$
      C = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}\sin\frac{\pi}{2}}=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}.
$$
Then $F(\pi/2)^2=\pi/2 \sin(\pi/2)$.

The reason that the answer is "yes" is that
$$
                   \frac{1}{2}\oint_{|z|=\pi/2}\frac{\cos w}{\sin w}+\frac{1}{w}dw = 2\pi i,
$$
which ensures that the definition of $F$ does not require a branch cut. The function $F$ is holomorphic in $0 < |z| < \pi$ by its definition, and it remains bounded near $0$, which means that it has a removable singularity at $0$. The function $F$ is what you want because $F(\pi/2)=\sqrt{\pi/2\sin(\pi/2)}$, and because
$$
  \frac{d}{dz}\frac{F(z)^2}{z\sin z}
    = 0.
$$

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, @TrialAndError :-)

Comment: @User001 : You're welcome.